# Java/Eclipse: Export classes, interfaces AND REFERENCED LIBRARIES to a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I wrote several java-classes and -interfaces.
These classes are using a referenced library. 
Without the referenced library, the classes won't work.

I want to export these classes/interfaces to a jar-File. Not a runnable jar, because i want to use this jar-File as a library later.

But it seems, after creating my jar-file, that my referenced library is not included.

Does anyone have an idea, what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a project which uses an external jar, in order to execute it you need the library's classes to be in your classpath.
You can achieve this through several ways:

- When executing your jar, add to the classpath the path to the referenced library
- Create a "lib" folder inside your project's structure and add it to your project. Inside Eclipse , right click on your project
- Use maven to compile and execute your jar, with the maven-dependency-plugin and the maven-jar-plugin. It will copy your jars and include them in the manifest.mf before executing your jar.
- Use maven-assembly-plugin to create a fat jar. It will open your referenced library jar and copy all the classes inside that library into your current project just before generating the jar. Thus, every class needed will be inside the jar.